# what is the best sampling procedure to use? (stratified)

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sampling, stratification

all,

i am a little confused on what sampling method to use. i am doing a classification problem where i am trying to classify a person as having cancer or not. there is apparently huge variance in this due to age group. e.g. 20-30 year old is more likely to have cancer (i.e. be labelled 1 ) compared to one in 10-20 year old group. so i have 3 stratas: 10-20, 20-30, 50-60. in the first grup only 1% have cancer, in the final group 5% have cancer.

i plan to take a random sample from each group say 10,000 - but in doing so i keep the proportions of cancer : to no cancer the same using stratfied. i do this for each age group. i then combine all the data together.

my question is... should i not do the above and instead combine all the groups together then take a random sample. e.g. if full popultion of is 600k, i would take all this and take a sample using stratified to now what is representative of whole population.. ?

i am in two minds and unsure.

Comment: I think you should combine all the groups together and consider age as an important feature.

Comment: Why not the other way